# angular js input bind value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an input like this :

```
<input ng-model="mysearch.myfield" id="myid"/>
```

that is bound to a filter

```
<table><tr ng-repeat="row in list|filter:mysearch">...</tr></table>
```

If I modify the input value in the GUI, it works perfectly, but if I try to modify its value via javascript/jquery

```
$("#myid").val("newvalue")
```

The input value is updated but the mysearch.myfield is not modified

Actually, I have a list that appears on user actions (it does not exist on page load):

```
<li onclick="changeTheInputValue('newvalue1')">newvalue1</li>
<li onclick="changeTheInputValue('newvalue2')">newvalue2</li>
...
```

with

```
function changeTheInputValue(v) {
  $("#myid").val(v);
}
```

And it does not work when I click on an "li" (the input value is updated, ut the mysearch.myfield is not modified)

I also tried

```
<li ng-click="mysearch.myfield = 'newvalue1'">newvalue1</li>
<li ng-click="mysearch.myfield = 'newvalue2'">newvalue2</li>
...
```

but it does not work :( 
Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: When you change the value outside of the Angular context (e.g. from jQuery) Angular does not know about it (so it never happened as far as Angular is concerned). Your last approach **[should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Pkth3/)** though. What version of Angular are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

any javascript executing outside the angulars event loop won't be efective in angular untill you apply it. in order to do that you need to get the relevant scope and $apply the changes, since is not clear, how and why you are modifying the value outside the angular scope there is nothing much i can say except you could do something like

```
function changeTheInputValue(v) {
     $("#myid").val(v);
     angular.element($("#myid")).scope().$apply();
}
```

that should let angular know about the changes, how ever this is a bad design if using angular. there are far better ways to accomplish this same thing w/o having mixed execution scopes. (angular/the rest);

Comment: with out knowing how the layout is distributed could ver well be that the list is ouside the controllers scope

Comment: It could...But is it ?

Comment: well, lets get out of darkness and request for a more wider picture of the html in question

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the value of the input `"#myid"` using direct DOM manipulation. AngularJS is not aware of this. If you want both the html and the value of `mysearch.myfield` to update correctly, you must do so by modifying the `mysearch.myfield` property directly, either in a controller or via an ng-model binding or something similar.

The main reason this isn't working for you has to do with how AngularJS modifies the DOM. When you use jQuery to modify the DOM, you are circumventing angular. Angular has no way of knowing if you have changed something in the DOM except if you do it directly through Angular itself. In particular, if you are curious, read about the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) and [$digest](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest) services.

Hope this helps shed some light on the subject!